# Angular show list in alphabetical order and also show divider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**please anyone can help me i want to print list in Angularjs like this **
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7gTx.jpg)

Comment: have you tried orderBy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter each group by the letters you want.  Here's a  [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6DIGzHfG1X4xEUCD5Rtk?p=preview) Using this list:

```
$scope.myList = [{
    id: 11,
    name: 'Okra'
}, {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Musa'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Sky'
}, {
    id: 13,
    name: 'India'
}, {
    id: 14,
    name: 'Rose'
}, {
    id: 15,
    name: 'Titanic'
}, {
    id: 16,
    name: 'Onion'
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Germany'
}, {
    id: 17,
    name: 'Beer'
}, {
    id: 18,
    name: 'Run'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Garden'
}, {
    id: 19,
    name: 'Mountain'
}]
```

One function to get the alphabets between the two:

```
function genCharArray(charA, charZ) {
var a = [], i = charA.charCodeAt(0), j = charZ.charCodeAt(0);
for (; i <= j; ++i) {
    a.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
return a;
```

};

Then your filter:

```
app.filter("cfilter", function () {
return function (input, x, y) {
    var groups = [];
    var letters = genCharArray(x, y);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < letters.length; x++) {
            if (input[i].name.substring(0, 1) == letters[x])
                groups.push(input[i]);
        }

    } return groups;
}
```

});

And your HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="w in myList | cfilter: 'A':'H' | orderBy: 'name'">
  <div>{{w.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: how can i  implement this code for years 
for example 
<div ng-repeat="w in myList | cfilter: '2010':'2016' | orderBy: 'year'">
  <div>{{w.year}}</div>

Answer (score 2):

Use Order by

```
    $scope.friends = [
    {name: 'John',   phone: '555-1212',  age: 10},
    {name: 'Mary',   phone: '555-9876',  age: 19},
    {name: 'Mike',   phone: '555-4321',  age: 21},
    {name: 'Adam',   phone: '555-5678',  age: 35},
    {name: 'Julie',  phone: '555-8765',  age: 29}
  ];             
     <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'name'">
```

[read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: i want list like that
https://www.yourmechanic.com/book/
after open this link enter zip-code  78766
then below a car list appear i am exactly want list lik that

Comment: there are some way to do it and need time and you haven't write a single line code. i can only advice you here how can you do it. for example on that website you do filter on list and and group them as alphabetic order and show them in your html.

Answer (score 0):

create one directive pass an array of letter and range of alphabates you want to disaply.

```
<dummy-directive data="arrayData" range="A-G"></dummy-directive>
<dummy-directive data="arrayData" range="H-L></dummy-directive>
<dummy-directive data="arrayData" range="M-P"></dummy-directive>
<dummy-directive data="arrayData" range="Q-Z"></dummy-directive>
```

Now question is that how to implement directive?
we will display sorted data.

Comment: i want dynamically  set range with respect to data and same for years

Comment: yes you can set range in controller on data. and pass that